# Drawing on canvas calculate position wrong

Tags: android, canvas

I am trying to create sudoku view by using canvas class. I have checked my calculation several times and it seems by calculation is correct. But there are some space between rectangle and bottom line. Why does canvas calculate position wrong?

Here is my code;

```
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    this.mCanvasWidth = w;
    this.mCanvasHeight = h;

    Log.i(TAG, "onSizeChanged: Width: " + mCanvasWidth + ", " + "Height: " + mCanvasHeight);

}



@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);


    float padding = 10;
    float cellWidth = (mCanvasWidth - (4 * mBoldStrokeWidth) - (6 * mThinStrokeWidth) - (padding * 2)) / 9;

    canvas.drawLine(padding, padding + mBoldStrokeWidth / 2, mCanvasWidth - padding * 2, padding + mBoldStrokeWidth / 2, mBoldStrokePaint);
    canvas.drawLine(padding, cellWidth + mBoldStrokeWidth / 2, mCanvasWidth - padding * 2, cellWidth + mBoldStrokeWidth / 2, mBoldStrokePaint);

    RectF rectF = new RectF(padding, padding + mBoldStrokeWidth, cellWidth, cellWidth);
    canvas.drawRect(rectF, mDarkCellPaint);
}
```

result;

[image]

Comment: Looks like you have missed exactly 1 row of pixels. It could be several things: `setAntiAlias()`; your stroke settings for `mDarkCellPaint`; the fact that `mBoldStrokeWidth` could be an integer, and it has to render into discrete pixels, so you may get an odd "row" of pixels on either the top or the bottom of the bold-stroke line.

Comment: I have already set anti alias. I found this my cellWidth calculation returns float and it needs to be int so I casted it to the integer. This solved the issue on my phone but layout design page still same.

Comment: I also changed mBoldStroke with type from float to int and it solved my issue.